# Forcibly taking the throne of a strong military kingdom, with quasi-invincibility

Tags: earth-like, government, super-powers

A man almost invincible to physical damage (regeneration from any damage in few seconds), with the power to kill people in few seconds from mid to short distance and being an exceptional swordsman, wants to become the king of the kingdom with the most powerful military force of his (medieval-like) world.

"Almost" because he has a weakness (that's the point of the story) that can turn him vulnerable to a quick death, however normal humans can't take advantage from this weakness, as only a specific group of humans have the power for such. Such group lives isolated and independent from the rest of the world and have no interest in killing him. That's the weakness for his invincibility, but he's still vulnerable to other ways of dying, like drowning, decapitation, etc. Basically, there's no "magic" in this world, only the casting of elements (fire, wind, etc.) by using a special type of energy (but these elements alone aren't enough for killing him), which this group can use.

So in order to become king, he plans on invading such kingdom and killing the current king. But he doesn't want to make noise and call attention, and just want to achieve his goal silently.

And here's the point of this question: What would be the obstacles for him to achieve his goal?

---

<sup><sub>In case anyone wonders: that's just the story's beginning and most relevant info for this question.</sub></sup>

Comment: On casting elements, you have a task to convince the reader that this is not magic and "using a special type of energy" is not enough. Yet, that's beside the point. You don't need to kill this man, you just need imprison him, trap him, bury him alive - will die of old age?

Comment: does he fell pain ?

Comment: If you try to take power by force, you will end up in jail. Even if you can regen fast, you still can be capture, hit on the head, a net to capture. Then what can you do ? Well, you are a treats for the kingdom. You can end up dead quickly, drowning a witch is common, regen is black magic after all. Or he can play with you by torturing you for a long time. Regeneration will be his curse !

Comment: This question could easily be rewritten as: "What plot points do I need to slow or prevent the villain from achieving his goal?" The "obstacles" can be whatever you want/need them to be, which makes this either opinion-based or story-based.

Comment: @Theraot But if he can kill people from mid distance in few seconds, he would only be imprisoned, trapped or buried if he let them do it. About aging, no, because of his regeneration ability he doesn't get old.

Comment: @Frostfyre But he needs to conquer such kingdom, because that's from where all the story will be led from.

Comment: @BrunoLopes how does that power work? is this AOE? does it require awareness? Because you can just mob him. Aside form that you don't need to get close to him to throw trapping weapons (traping net, bolas, etc...) - and there is the option to trick him to fall into a trapping pit. Another question, how about poison, narcotics, hallucinogens?

Comment: @Theraot It looks like some kind of dark cloud, released from his hands on demand, that kills anything it touches, including an entire group of people. About substances, any that causes some kind of damage (like poison) he is quickly healed from them. But other types of substances affect him the same way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The biggest problem is making the step from being a regicide to being king.

As it stands he's simply a man who murdered the king, the next king is the previous king's eldest son, or other heir. To become king, he needs to be the heir to the throne and a following of nobles who support him, have a legitimate claim to the throne and a following of nobles who support him, or be a fairly high ranking noble himself and have a following of nobles who support him. There's a general theme that I'm hoping you've spotted here.

You say he heals, but does he still get tired? There are only so many people that one man can kill in a day, no matter how good a swordsman he is. He needs an army and support from at least a portion of the incumbent nobility. Kings are appointed by god, if people were allowed to fight their way to the top of the pile you'd never have a stable country.

In practice kings are accepted or deposed by the loyalty of the noble families, who in turn keep an eye on the population, and when they don't like a king and there's another heir available you get the [eternal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Anarchy) civil [wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wars_of_the_Roses) that [spread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Civil_War) throughout [the](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glorious_Revolution) middle ages.

*It should be noted that if he can drown then he can hang, and hanging is probably what will happen to him if he tries this without political support.*

Answer (score 4):

1. Create or stir up a threat to the kingdom
2. Defeat said threat
3. Marry the princess (or prince, if that is applicable)
4. Arrange accidents for other heirs to the throne
5. Initiate succession

Answer (score 2):

The man wants to be king and not be noticed. Easy, kill and impersonate the king, usurp the throne.

The obstacles:

- The army
- The royal guard
- The people close to the king
- The castle/palace where the king is
- The bad disguise of the king the man pulls up
- The disposition of the cadaver
- The intimate time with the queen
- The other man who is also trying to kill the king

Answer (score 1):

Simply convince the current king that you can kill him and his family at any time you wish and there is nothing he can do about it. Then tell him that you have no wish to replace him and his family from the top of social hierarchy and he can remain the king as far as outsiders can tell, keep his titles and social influence. Even let him keep some of the wealth and actual power. Treat him fair and with respect.

Essentially he would be your vassal. Nobody else would need to know this, so risk of countermeasures from others would be low.

Comment: So he would just take the authority but wouldn't be officially announced as king, right?

Comment: @BrunoLopes He would not be **publically** announced the king. Official, but "need to know", recognition of his status would be possible. In general, if you are worried about countermeasures somebody might do if they know about something, adjusting what you do and adjusting what is known about what you do are the two first steps. Optimizing your methods to make you less vulnerable should be distant third on the list.